# Error logging in to Stack overflow app with Facebook

Tags: bug, ios-app

I am attempting to log in to the new Stack Overflow app using the "Facebook" button.  This is how I log in to the site and how I have logged in to the Stack Exchange app.

After authorising the app (or confirming that I have already authorised the app when I try again) the Facebook browser windows closes and then an alert is shown "Login Error - No email address is associated with this Facebook account".  I have several email addresses registered on my Facebook account.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue when I developed a website with option to login with Facebook. if I remember correctly you also need [verify](https://www.facebook.com/help/376335499080938/) your email address, otherwise it will not be available to the FB app.

Answer (score 2):

The copy is not the best here.  After we log into Facebook, we check for the `email` field on the current user with `/me`.  This is the email address we test against the user database.  If the field is nil, we display that error.

According to [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016), there are a variety of reasons for this:

> - No Email address on account
> - No confirmed email address on account
> - No verified email address on account
> - User entered a security checkpoint which required them to reconfirm their email address and they have not yet done so
> - Users's email address is unreachable

One of these situations may apply to your account.  I'm gonna ruminate on how to better rephrase the error message.

Comment: Thanks.  What I don't understand is why the Stack Exchange app has no problem with Facebook authentication and neither does the site.  I checked my account and I have several email addresses.  There is no "verify" button shown next to any of them, so I presume they are verified although I have had my Facebook account for many years, so it is possible that there is some issue related to Facebook changes since the emails were added